# Can't run PHPUnit

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpunit, pear

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install PEAR and PHPUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994811/how-to-install-pear-and-phpunit)

I'm using Ubuntu and trying to install PHPUnit. I've installed PEAR using apt-get, and currently it's installed in /usr/lib/pear.

And to install PHPUnit, I ran the commands:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

And installed dependencies

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml
```

And installed PHPUnit

```
pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

But I still can't run `phpunit` in the command line. I've noticed there's a phpunit inside my pear directory on /home/username/pear, but how do I add it to my path? Thanks

Comment: Try re-login. it might work.

Comment: What does `which phpunit` return?

Comment: which phpunit returns nothing. re-login also did not work.

Comment: It looks like that you didn't properly install PEAR and that you are not using PEAR properly. Please consult the PEAR documentation how to install and how to use it. If there is anything special with Ubtun, also consult the support resources for the Pear and Phpunit package on that linux disturation community. Additionally this smells much like a duplicate to your own, previous question which got closed for a reason: [How to install PEAR and PHPUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13994811/367456) - Instead improve your exisiting question and keep a worklog what you've done so far.

Comment: Do not only post the commands but also which output you get. Thank you.

Comment: First run `$ pear config-get bin_dir` and then `PATH=$PATH:/home/username/pear/bin/` (adjust as needed)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you've run the pear commands as a normal user: you have to run them as root, to install system-wide. (I.e. everywhere you've written `pear` in your question, write `sudo pear` instead.)

(If you deliberately don't want them installed system-wide, edit the question to ask that.)

Comment: In a system-wide install, does phpunit get installed in /home/username/pear/bin? Because that's what happens in my case. I've also tried running all of the pear with sudo, but still can't run phpunit.

Comment: @beefjerky: No, not in the user directory. install pear as root and call the pear command as root / sudo, too. also do `updatedb` and then `locate phpunit`, or first the locate, if it finds nothing, updatedate and then locate again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including the autoloader manually in your test.

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoloader.php';
```

Comment: I'm running it in the command line.

Comment: That still requires php classes to be included correctly. But this doesn't seem to be your primary problem here. Your phpunit binary needs to be in or linked into or its path added to the environment variable `PATH`. What does `phpunit --version` run anywhere result in?

Comment: running phpunit --version gives me 'The program 'phpunit' is currently not installed.' I've already tried adding phpunit to my PATH variable, adding in /home/username/pear/bin, but still no luck.